# Nesting blocks of different types in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm trying to alter the product pages on my Magento install. In the current theme, product options are shown in the main part of the page. I'm trying to get them to show up in a more-information tab instead. The problem appears to be that the product options are created by a structural block of XML, and I can't just move that into another position, it needs to be 'translated.'

Here's the product-options chunk of XML:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
    <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
    <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
    </block>
</block>
```

So there's a `catalog/product_view` block there to which several chucnks of PHTML are added. Okay. However, the XML that creates the tabs, asks for something different. Here's a sample:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>options</alias>
        <title>Options</title>
        <block>catalog/product_view</block>
        <template>catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml</template>
    </action>
</block>
```

The `<block>foo/bar_baz</block>` bit there is clearly a different type of block than the main blocks here. How can I insert a structural block there? I'm trying to get it so that the whole bundle of content generated by the first quoted XML blob, can be used in the `<block>` tag nested inside `<action method="addTab">`.

---

For bonus points, what are the actual names of those two different use cases for `<block>`, what is the difference between the *contents* of a `<block>` tag and its *attributes*, and where on this lovely green Earth is any of this documented?

---

Here's the block of XML that ended up working for me, based on Sergei's answer.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>product_options_wrapper</alias>
        <title>Options</title>
        <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
        <template>catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <!-- Inserting an extra block that will generate the content of the Options tab. -->
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </block>
</block>
```

Comment: Can you precise your bonus question? I do think I can help you with details, but cannot fully understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question: I looked through the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Tabs` class and examined the `addTab` function:

```
    function addTab($alias, $title, $block, $template) {
        if (!$title || !$block || !$template) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->_tabs[] = array(
        'alias' => $alias,
        'title' => $title
        );

        $this->setChild($alias,
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock($block, $alias)->setTemplate($template)
        );
}
```

So you can see that every element passed as an argument is added to the private `_tabs` array and also is added as a Child of the current block. The function doesn't accept other parameters, which is inconvenient.

This is how all of the tabs are rendered in `catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml`:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
    <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
```

That tells us that a tab will render only content that is assigned to the private `_tabs` array *and* has a child block with an `alias` property that matches the value of `$_tab['alias']`. However, what we can about that is to add a tab, and then substitute in the block content we want with the standard Magento method of defining a block with the same name and overriding.

Here's a working example based on your code:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>description</alias>
        <title>description</title>
        <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
        <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>product_options</alias>
        <title>test</title>
        <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
        <template>catalog/product/view/dummy_example.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <reference name="product_options">
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</block>
```

This gives us tabs rendered on the frontend with the options displayed in their own tab.

Here's how we actually got that:

1. We generated a list of `childHtml` blocks with the `<action method="addTab">` tags.
2. We created a new block, `product.info.options`, with the content we want, and used `as="product_options"` to give it the same alias as the block that the `addTab` method is looking for.
3. The `addTab` method uses our new block and its template instead of the `dummy_example.phtml` template when it looks for a block with the alias "`product_options`", and the net effect is that our block and its `options.phtml` template gets rendered instead of `dummy_example.phtml`.

**UPDATE**. Replaced `block` creating with `reference` to already existing one. Now this solution is more reliable.

Comment: Okay, that's helpful and it looks promising. What's this? `<template>catalog/product/view/care.phtml</template>` - that phtml file isn't part of my Magento installation. It looks like something you were using to test your answer. What's in that file?

Comment: yes, that's from my test environment. File is similar to `description.phtml` but for custom attribute `care`. in this example it is not so important cause attribute created with this data will be overwritten in the end. just replace it with description.phtml

Comment: Ahah! Okay, it took some wrangling, but I got that solution working. Thank you.

Comment: Thnx for text revision. Didn't know my english is so harsh.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that the answer could help others as much as it helped me. :)